# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' en PYCARET

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

El problema que tengo es que estoy trabajando con los datos de  [water potability](https://www.kaggle.com/adityakadiwal/water-potability) los cuales no tienen ningún string, y a la hora de ejecutar el setup para  los modelos de clasificación me salta el siguiente error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Y no comprendo la razón si todas mis variables son del tipo int y float. Para comprobar cuál era el problema  lo que hice fue:

- Convertir la única columna  int64 a float64 .
- Eliminar columnas para ver si alguna en específico daba el problema .
- Eliminar todas las columnas y dejar solamente 2 ("ph" y "potability").

Mi código únicamente es:

```
 df = pd.read_csv("water_potability.csv", header = "infer")
 model = setup(data =df, target =  "Potability")
```

Comment: Es posible que esté tomando las filas en las que se indica el nombre de las columnas o variables por ello te salta ese error, porque está intentando operar algo de tipo entero con algo de tipo string. Espero que te haya ayudado.

Comment: si solo has dejado dos columnas y aún te da error, fijate probando de a una, por ejemplo:  model = setup(data =df, target =  "Potability",ignore_features = ['ph']) y después con potability

Answer (score 1):

Ese conjunto de datos, contiene varios datos que son `NaN` (Not a Number), según el proceso que has descrito en la pregunta, no has hecho nada para tratarlos. Ejecutando la siguiente sentencia se puede ver el número de `NaN` por columnas:

```
#He llamado al conjunto de datos df_water porque df es muy genérico
df_water.isna().sum()
```

**Salida:**

```
ph                 491
Hardness             0
Solids               0
Chloramines          0
Sulfate            781
Conductivity         0
Organic_carbon       0
Trihalomethanes    162
Turbidity            0
Potability           0
dtype: int64
```

Si le introduces al modelo datos que no son números `NaN` el modelo fallará. Necesitas tratar esos datos, maneras hay muchas,

- Borrar las filas o las columnas que son `NaN`, puedes conseguirlo con el método de Pandas `.dropna()`, quedaría así `df_water.dropna()`
- Con medias, medianas y otras estadisticas básicas.
- Interpolación más avanzada con modelización, es decir utilizar modelos para predecir los datos que no tienes.